# Differentiability of antiderivative and continuity of derivative

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a,b\in \mathbb{R}: a<b$. Let $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$, $f$ is monotone increasing. Let $F:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto \int_{[a,x]} f$.

Show that if $F$ is differentiable at $x_0 \in [a,b]$, then $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.

If f was not continuous, then the right and left limits would not match. Because the function jumps, its measure has to jump too, therefore integral would be discontinuous and therefore non differentiable. However I do not know how to formalize this intiuition.

Comment: This is not true at the endpoints. It is true for $a<x_0<b$ however

Comment: @zhw.: for end points one can restrict to one sided derivatives and continuity.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I don't think so. Consider $f(x)= 0, a\le x<b,$ $f(b)=1.$ Here $F'(b)=0$ from the left, but $f$ is not continuous at $b.$

Comment: @zhw.: yes you are right the one sided derivative of $F$ is equal to one sided limit of $f$ which may not equal value of $f$. Unlike you sometimes I miss the fine points in haste.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Let $x\in (a,b).$ As you said, $f$ has limits $f_-(x),f_+(x)$ from the left and right. Show that this implies $F$ has left and right derivatives $f_-(x),f_+(x)$ at $x.$